# Failed to build workspace Alamofire with scheme Alamofire watchOS

Tags: alamofire

I used Carthage to manage my project,however when I import Alamofire, I got the following errors:

> Building scheme "Alamofire watchOS" in Alamofire.xcworkspace
>
> xcodebuild: error: Failed to build workspace Alamofire with scheme Alamofire watchOS.
>
> Reason: The run destination My Mac is not valid for Running the scheme 'Alamofire watchOS'.
>
> A shell task failed with exit code 70:
>
> xcodebuild: error: Failed to build workspace Alamofire with scheme Alamofire watchOS.
>
> Reason: The run destination My Mac is not valid for Running the scheme 'Alamofire watchOS'.

PS:cartfile content is :`github "Alamofire/Alamofire" ~> 3.0`

Can anyone help me? many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need to build the framework for watchOS, then be more selective about the platform you need.

```
$ carthage update --platform iOS
```

If you do in fact need the watchOS framework, then make sure you have watch simulators set up in your Xcode device manager. Otherwise there are a handful of carthage errors you can run into.

One final thing to remember is that you MUST be using Xcode 7 in order to use Alamofire 3.0.